# Qual o comando para listas os arquivos começados por “a” e terminados por “v”?

Tags: linux

Possuo um arquivo a.txt que dentro dele possui adsaadv
Gostaria de procurar além dele outros arquivos começados por a e terminados por v.

Pensei em usar o grep algo como, grep "^[a-v$]" a.txt

Porém, não obtive sucesso, tenho que mesclar comandos de grep com algo mais ?

Agradeço se puderem me dar uma clariada.

Comment: a regex `^a(.*)v$` dá o resultado esperado?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls | grep ^a.*v$
```

- `ls` lista o diretório
- `|` o *pipe* manda a saída do `ls` para o `grep`
- `grep` filtra a entrada com uma expressão regular, e devolve na saída por padrão
- `^` é o começo da linha
- `a` é o caractere logo no começo da linha
- `.*` o ponto significa "qualquer caractere". O asterisco significa "quantos caracteres tiver"
- `v` é o caractere que você quer no final
- `$` é o fim da linha

Como você quer a extensão, ajuste para:

```
ls | grep ^a.*v\.txt$
```

- a `\` significa que o ponto seguinte é um ponto de fato, e não um coringa de *RegEx*.

Comment: Agora foi perfeitamente, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: eventualmente com plicas:  ...`grep 'a.*v\.txt$' `

Comment: @JJoao quando tem certos caracteres no meio até precisa mesmo (espaços, por exemplo)

Answer (score 1):

nem precisa complicar tanto; o velho comando **ls** pode te ajudar nisso já muito facilmente.

Basta fazer um:

**ls a*v**

Mas você se expressou mal na pergunta, pois procura uma determinada combinação de texto dentro de um arquivo, então para solucionar seu problem, faça um:

grep [^a].[v$] a.txt

Comment: is a*v ne.txt ?
Deu command not found ou utiliza ele junto ao grep ?

Comment: Obrigado ai, agora funcionou, porem no retorno, selecionou em vermelho apenas o V, minha duvida era realmente como fazer duas buscas distintas eu estava tentando com [^a-v$]